# Convert a string to a number

Tags: php

I am retrieving a value from a CMS which I think may be adding some additional space to the value.

The value is held as a string but I need to convert it to an integer.

I am storing the result of the query in an array. When I loop through and check the values I'm getting unexpected output from `var_dump`.

Heres my code:

```
foreach ($non_approved_points as $value):
            echo $value;
            var_dump($value);
        endforeach;
```

Here’s the output:

```
90

string(9) "
90

"
```

It looks like the value is string of 9 characters. I've tried trim() and str_replace(). Any ideas how I can get the integer value from this?

Comment: Also `$int = (int)$value;`

Comment: Please ... [Google!](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convert%20string%20to%20int%20php)

Answer (score 2):

Then just use [`intval`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.intval.php) like this:

```
foreach ($non_approved_points as $value):
            $value = intval($value)
            echo $value;
            var_dump($value);
        endforeach;
```

If that somehow did not work—which I doubt—you could also use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with some regex to remove non-numerical values out of the string:

```
foreach ($non_approved_points as $value):
            $value = intval(preg_replace('/![0-9]+/', '' $value));
            echo $value;
            var_dump($value);
        endforeach;
```

The way you should look at the `intval` plus `preg_replace` combo is the `preg_replace` gets rid of non-numeric characters so it cleans it to one level. And then `intval` performs the final step make the cleaned string a proper integer.

Comment: Man, this is doing my head in. I've tried every single combination and I"m still getting the var_dump output as string(10) "
150

".WTF.

Comment: OK, I finally worked it out. I outputted the string into my markup and viewed the source. All values are being wrapped in <p> tags. A simple strip_tags() has fixed the issue. My question is why does the var_dump() not display the <p>?

Comment: Hi Jake, yes I was wondering the same. It wasn't until I outputted the code into the markup and checked the source using Chrome dev tools that I saw the P tags, up until that point I hadn't seen them. Strip tags fixed it eventually. Thanks for your help.